# how to find second last record from collection with meteor.js?

Tags: meteor

I would like to find 2nd last record form collection with Meteor. How can I get it. For example if I use SQL I will write query like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * From
(select Top 2 * from student ORDER BY Id DESC)                      
ORDER BY Id
```

How about in Meteor.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Collection.find({}, {sort: {Field: -1}, limit: n}).fetch().pop();
```

Where:

- `Collection` is your collection name.
- `Field` is the field you're interested in.
- You're looking for the `n`th last document.

Essentially, you're reverse-sorting by the given field, limiting the returned results to only the first `n`, and then popping off the last element in that result set (i.e. the `n`th).